# How to add multiple images from android and store them in a database

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating a user profile registration application which include user details and three photos of user. I successfully uploaded user details to database and I have no idea on how to upload the images to database. images are displaying in `Imageview`. Can any one help in this issue...?

private void initListeners() {
        appCompatButtonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

```
    profileImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    profileImageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
    profileImageView2.setOnClickListener(this);

    switch (clickImage) {
        case 1:
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                profileImageView.setEnabled(false);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            } else {
                profileImageView.setEnabled(true);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                profileImageView1.setEnabled(false);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            } else {
                profileImageView1.setEnabled(true);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                profileImageView2.setEnabled(false);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            } else {
                profileImageView2.setEnabled(true);
            }
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (clickImage) {
        case 1:
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    profileImageView.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    profileImageView1.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    profileImageView2.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * This method is to initialize objects to be used
 */
private void initObjects() {
    inputValidation = new InputValidation(activity);
}

/**
 * This implemented method is to listen the click on view
 *
 * @param v
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.appCompatButtonRegister:
            verifyData();
            break;

        case R.id.profileImageView:
            clickImage=0;
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title(R.string.uploadImages)
                    .items(R.array.uploadImages)
                    .itemsIds(R.array.itemIds)
                    .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                            switch (which) {

                                case 0:
                                    captureImage();
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    profileImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            break;
        case R.id.profileImageView1:
            clickImage=1;
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title(R.string.uploadImages)
                    .items(R.array.uploadImages)
                    .itemsIds(R.array.itemIds)
                    .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                            switch (which) {

                                case 0:
                                    captureImage();
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    profileImageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            break;
        case R.id.profileImageView2:
            clickImage=2;
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title(R.string.uploadImages)
                    .items(R.array.uploadImages)
                    .itemsIds(R.array.itemIds)
                    .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                            switch (which) {

                                case 0:
                                    captureImage();
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    profileImageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            break;



    }
}

/**
 * Launching camera app to capture image
 */
private void captureImage() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) { //use this if Lollipop_Mr1 (API 22) or above
        Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
        callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // We give some instruction to the intent to save the image
        File photoFile = null;

        try {
            // If the createImageFile will be successful, the photo file will have the address of the file
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            // Here we call the function that will try to catch the exception made by the throw function
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Exception error in generating the file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Here we add an extra file to the intent to put the address on to. For this purpose we use the FileProvider, declared in the AndroidManifest.
        Uri outputUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                photoFile);
        callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

        // The following is a new line with a trying attempt
        callCameraApplicationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Calling the camera App by intent");

        // The following strings calls the camera app and wait for his file in return.
        startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (clickImage) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        // Get the Image from data
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        assert cursor != null;
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
                        profileImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                        cursor.close();

                        postPath = mediaPath;
                    }


                } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {

                        Glide.with(this).load(mImageFileLocation).into(profileImageView);
                        postPath = mImageFileLocation;

                    } else {
                        Glide.with(this).load(fileUri).into(profileImageView);
                        postPath = fileUri.getPath();
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, there was an error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        // Get the Image from data
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        assert cursor != null;
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex1);
                        // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
                        profileImageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                        cursor.close();

                        postPath = mediaPath;
                    }


                } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {

                        Glide.with(this).load(mImageFileLocation).into(profileImageView1);
                        postPath = mImageFileLocation;

                    } else {
                        Glide.with(this).load(fileUri).into(profileImageView1);
                        postPath = fileUri.getPath();
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, there was an error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        // Get the Image from data
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        assert cursor != null;
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex1);
                        // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
                        profileImageView2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                        cursor.close();

                        postPath = mediaPath;
                    }


                } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {

                        Glide.with(this).load(mImageFileLocation).into(profileImageView2);
                        postPath = mImageFileLocation;

                    } else {
                        Glide.with(this).load(fileUri).into(profileImageView2);
                        postPath = fileUri.getPath();
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, there was an error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}

File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Generating the image - method started");

    // Here we create a "non-collision file name", alternatively said, "an unique filename" using the "timeStamp" functionality
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmSS").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp;
    // Here we specify the environment location and the exact path where we want to save the so-created file
    File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/photo_saving_app");
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Storage directory set");

    // Then we create the storage directory if does not exists
    if (!storageDirectory.exists()) storageDirectory.mkdir();

    // Here we create the file using a prefix, a suffix and a directory
    File image = new File(storageDirectory, imageFileName + ".jpg");
    // File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDirectory);

    // Here the location is saved into the string mImageFileLocation
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("File name and path set");

    mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
    fileUri = Uri.parse(mImageFileLocation);
    // The file is returned to the previous intent across the camera application
    return image;
}

/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
 * */

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + ".jpg");
    }  else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}


/**
 * This method is to validate the input text fields and post data to SQLite
 */
private void verifyData() {
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditFirmName, textInputLayoutFirmName, getString(R.string.error_message_name))) {
        return;
    }else if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextUserName, textInputLayoutUserName, getString(R.string.error_message_username))) {

        return;
    }else if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextAddress, textInputLayoutAddress, getString(R.string.error_message_password))) {
        return;
    }else if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextArea, textInputLayoutArea, getString(R.string.error_message_Area))) {
        return;
    }else if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextCity, textInputLayoutCity, getString(R.string.error_message_City))) {
        return;
    }else if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextMobileNum, textInputLayoutMobileNum, getString(R.string.error_message_Mobile))) {
        return;
    }else if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextConfirmEmail, textInputLayoutConfirmEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_Email))) {
        return;
    }else if (postPath == null || postPath.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "please select an image ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else{
        String firmname = textInputEditFirmName.getText().toString().trim();
        String username = textInputEditTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String addres = textInputEditTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();
        String area = textInputEditTextArea.getText().toString().trim();
        String cityy = textInputEditTextCity.getText().toString().trim();
        String mobilenum = textInputEditTextMobileNum.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = textInputEditTextConfirmEmail.getText().toString().trim();


        submitUserDetails(firmname, username, addres, area, cityy, mobilenum, email);
    }
}

@NonNull
private RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
    return RequestBody.create(
            okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);
}

@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName) {

    File file = new File(postPath);

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("*/*"),
                    file
            );

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}

private void submitUserDetails(String firmname, String username, String addres,String area,String cityy,String mobilenum,String email){
    showpDialog();
    UserService loginService = DataServiceGenerator.createService(UserService.class, getApplication(), USER_BASE_URL);

    // create part for file (photo, video, ...)
    MultipartBody.Part body = prepareFilePart("sender");

    // create a map of data to pass along
    RequestBody authName = createPartFromString(firmname);
    RequestBody authUsername = createPartFromString(username);
    RequestBody authAddress = createPartFromString(addres);
    RequestBody authArea = createPartFromString(area);
    RequestBody authCity = createPartFromString(cityy);
    RequestBody authMobile = createPartFromString(mobilenum);
    RequestBody authEmail = createPartFromString(email);


    HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("firmname", authName);
    map.put("username", authUsername);
    map.put("addres", authAddress);
    map.put("area", authArea);
    map.put("cityy", authCity);
    map.put("mobilenum", authMobile);
    map.put("email", authEmail);


    Call<Message> call = loginService.appuserinst(map, body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Message>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Message> call, Response<Message> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                if (response.body() != null){
                    hidepDialog();
                    Message message = response.body();
                    String regMessage = message.getMessage();
                    emptyInputEditText();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), regMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Message> call, Throwable t) {
            hidepDialog();
            Log.d(TAG, "the cause of crash " + t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * This method is to empty all input edit text
 */
private void emptyInputEditText() {
    textInputEditFirmName.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextUserName.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextAddress.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextArea.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextCity.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextMobileNum.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextConfirmEmail.setText(null);
}

protected void initpDialog() {

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_loading));
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
}


protected void showpDialog() {

    if (!pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.show();
}

protected void hidepDialog() {

    if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: Store them in an [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org) [blob](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) See [insert-and-retrieve-image](https://www.designstring.com/insert-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android/)

Comment: Please, format your code to complete your question. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask